# Cant understand this variadic template example

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

While trying to understand the concept of variadic templates. I came across this example. This seems to be a minimalistics example for me.

```
void output()   --------->function A
{ cout << "This is the results\n"; }

template <typename T, typename ...P> 
void output(T t, P ...p)  ------->functionB
{
  cout << t << ' ';
 { 
     output(p...); ------>statement A
 }

}


//Test it
int main()
{
  output('5', 2);

  return(0);
}
```

Now the output of the above program is:

```
5 2 This is the results
```

Here are some questions that I had regarding this example:

1)What is statement A calling ? is it calling the function A ? But it only seems to call it once ?Also the method does not have any parameters in its signature ? How did I get `5 2 This is the results` in the above example as the output

2)What does it mean when the author states that variadic classes are recursive and thus they require a base class

Comment: You didn't read carefully. It's "base case", not "base class".

Comment: I think this should be covered in any tutorial on variadic templates, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change your example to:

```
int g = 0;

void output() { cout << "This is the results\n"; }

template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  cout << "\n\tg = " << g++ << endl;
  cout << t << ' ';
  {
    output(p...);
   }
 }
```

The output will be:

```
g = 0
5 
g = 1
2 This is the results
```

So when you invoke output('5', 2);
the compiler will generate code what will do following:

```
void output(char c, int x)
{
   cout << c << ' ';
   output(x);
}
```

Then it will "recursively" generate the function:

```
void output(int x) {
   cout << x << ' ';
   output();  
}
```

For the base case you have already defined "void output()":

```
void output() { cout << "This is the results\n"; }
```

so a compiler will use it instead of generating a code from the template.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This cleared it up

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What is statement A calling ? is it calling the function A ? But it
>   only seems to call it once ?Also the method does not have any
>   parameters in its signature ? How did I get 5 2 This is the results in
>   the above example as the output

When you call the function like this:

```
output('5', 2);
```

`t == '5'` and `...p` will be the rest of the arguments which is only `2`

```
void output(T t, P ...p)
//           '5'    { 2 }
```

You are then printing the first type `char`:

```
cout << t << ' ';
//     '5'
```

And then you are calling the function again (*recursion*) with the rest of the arguments:

```
output(p...); // p is only {2}
```

Again you print out only the number `2`:

```
cout << t << ' ';
//      2
```

And there are no arguments left, and it will call the base case:

```
void output()
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. While your answer was more informative. I would have to mark Vadims answer as it was posted earlier. He gave me a clue on how to figure it out and I had to go to the drawing board to figure it out and experiment.Reading your answer confirms my findings and it was way easier to understand . I really appreciate you chiming in and posting a great and a brief explanation.